# bashscript mulitiple condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote a script which makes a backup to a mounted disk in `/mount/data/` and I dont want to copy that folder while copying the others there and I dont want to copy the `proc`, `sys` also

```
for dir in `ls /`; do
if [ $dir != "mount" -o $dir != "proc" -o $dir != "sys" ]; then
   sh /home/bin/safecopy $dir
fi
done
```

but the condition is ignored

```
$dir != "mount" -o $dir != "proc" -o $dir != "sys"
```

and the `safecopy` try to copy `mount`, `proc` and `sys` ... why ?

but when I do this

```
for dir in `ls /`; do
    if [ $dir != "mount" ]; then
    if [ $dir != "proc" ]; then
    if [ $dir != "sys" ]; then
       sh /home/bin/safecopy $dir
    fi
    fi
    fi
done
```

it works!

Comment: Take a close look at your condition: You are using `or` instead of `and`.

Comment: This would be better coded with a case: case dir in mount|proc|sys);; *) sh /home/bin/safecopy $dir;; esac

Comment: You could also do: test $dir = mount && continue; test $dir = proc && continue...

Comment: Why `for dir in \`ls /\`` when `for dir in /*` works and isn't horribly broken?

Comment: @Sorpigal `/*/` actually, though people don't typically have regular files under `/`.

Comment: If you don't need POSIX compatibility in your script, you can use the "new test" by putting the `[[` and `]]` constructs into use. People usually find them more intuitive. Read all about it : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Answer (score 5):

A good way assuming it's required to run on shells other than Bash is to use `case`, since it supports pattern matching (unlike `[`):

```
for dir in /*/; do
    case $dir in
        /mount/|/proc/|/sys/)
            :
            ;;
        *)
            /home/bin/safecopy "$dir"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

For Bash specifically, you can use:

```
shopt -s extglob
for dir in /!(mount|proc|sys)/; do
    /home/bin/safecopy "$dir"
done
```

- Never iterate over, or even use `ls` in a script.
- Never word-split command substitution output, quote them.
- Never use backticks, use `"$(cmd)"`.
- Never use `-a` or `-o` when using the classic `test` command (`[`). Use [ test ] || [ test ] ...
- Use quotes! They're missing in several important places.
- You shouldn't have to call "`safecopy`" with "sh" if no special arguments to `sh` are needed. Add a shebang to the script and call it like any other command, or if it's a library, source it and use its functions directly.

Comment: As opposed to "Never" as I am, at least when it comes to programming, these rules are definitely worth remembering. +1

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Certainly yes, though shell grammar is rather complicated - if people are making basic mistakes like these it's probably better that they stick to the "rules". These particular guidelines are pretty well agreed upon.

Comment: +1. The master may feel free to ignore any rule he likes, the novice should stick to them religiously.

Comment: -1 for not actually working -- `/*/` will expand to e.g. `/mount/`, not e.g. `mount`, so the `mount|proc|sys)` needs to be `/mount/|/proc/|/sys/)` -- but if you fix that, I'll +1 your answer and delete mine. (I wouldn't normally -1 for something so easily corrected, but one unjustified -1 deserves another. ;-) )

Comment: @ruakh Good point, patterns != globs - I normally wouldn't actually use the 1st solution, nor would I normally -1 something that isn't actually wrong, so you get de-thumbs down anyway. :) Just thought I'd warn folks.